# Get a list of countries available for shipping with Ajax in Craft Commerce

Tags: ajax, plugin-craftcommerce3

I need to fetch a list countries available for shipping in Craft Commerce.

The problem is that I use decoupled frontend on Nuxt.js and I need fetch it with Ajax call and not with the twig code.

I tried to call it in a Postman but it returns me a 403 - Forbidden error with message "User is not permitted to perform this action".

I couldn't find something about the way of making request through Ajax in Commerce documentation, can you please tell me what I'm doing wrong here?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You need to provide a CSRF token, alternatively turn it off in your config/general.php file.

Set a token in your twig template:

```
{% set csrfToken = {
    csrfTokenName: craft.app.config.general.csrfTokenName,
    csrfTokenValue: craft.app.request.csrfToken,
} %}

<script type="text/javascript">
    window.Craft = {{ csrfToken|json_encode|raw }};
</script>
```

Then include the CSRF token name and value in your post array (data):

```
data[window.Craft.csrfTokenName] = window.Craft.csrfTokenValue;
```

Alternatively you can set enableCsrfProtection to false in your general config file.

Comment: CSRF protection is disabled, still I'm getting an error. Also I use headless Craft together with decoupled frontend on Nuxt.js, so I need a way to fetch data with axios on Nuxt.js without using a twig template code.

Answer (score 2):

The [controller action you are hitting](https://github.com/craftcms/commerce/blob/develop/src/controllers/CountriesController.php#L34-L39) returns a template and I think that it is why you are getting this error.

If you don't have `headlessMode` on ([docs](https://craftcms.com/docs/3.x/config/config-settings.html#headlessmode)) you could make a quick template, add:

```
{% header "Content-Type: application/json"%}
{{ craft.commerce.countries.getAllCountries() | json_encode() | raw }}
```

Which would give you an endpoint you can then reach from your front end.

Alternatively, you could [make a small module/plugin](https://craftcms.com/docs/3.x/extend/) with a [controller](https://craftcms.com/docs/3.x/extend/controllers.html).

Answer (score 1):

After enabling the headless mode in Craft I'm getting the same error in JSON format:

[image]

Anyway I guess I have to write some module for that extra functionality.
Thank you for the tips!